# Use Syphon to send Processing frames to VPT

Tags: processing, syphon

I'm using Processing with FaceOSCSyphon and need to use Syphon to send the frames from Processing to VPT. What do I need to add to my code for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used FaceOSCSyphon, but played a bit with the FaceTracker library. Looking at the examples, the [FaceOSCSyphon.pde](https://github.com/CreativeInquiry/FaceOSC-Templates/blob/master/processing/FaceOSCSyphon/FaceOSCSyphon.pde) sketch acts a a Syphon Client.

In your case, according to page 33 of the [VPT Documentation](http://nervousvision.com/vpt/vpt7_Documentation.pdf)(large pdf link), your Processing sketch needs to be a Syphon Server.

In Processing run **Examples > Contributed Libraries > Syphon > Send Frames**.

In VPT, scroll the layer list on the right towards the bottom until you find the `syph` section. You should then be able to choose the Processing Syphon server ran by the Send Frames example:

[image: Syphon input in VPT]

[image: Processing Sketch in Syphon]

Now you should have a clear idea of how to get frames from Processing into VPT.

Regarding the FaceOSC part, I'd recommend merging the SendFrames example with the [FaceOSCReceiverClass](https://github.com/CreativeInquiry/FaceOSC-Templates/blob/master/processing/FaceOSCReceiverClass/FaceOSCReceiverClass.pde) example: read the FaceOSC data, but instead of setting up a Syphon Client, setup a Syphon Server.

For example:

```
//
// a template for receiving face tracking osc messages from
// Kyle McDonald's FaceOSC https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxFaceTracker
//
// this example includes a class to abstract the Face data
//
// 2012 Dan Wilcox danomatika.com
// for the IACD Spring 2012 class at the CMU School of Art
//
// adapted from from Greg Borenstein's 2011 example
// http://www.gregborenstein.com/
// https://gist.github.com/1603230
//
import codeanticode.syphon.*;
import oscP5.*;
OscP5 oscP5;

PGraphics canvas;
SyphonServer server;


// our FaceOSC tracked face dat
Face face = new Face();

void setup() {
  size(640, 480,P2D);
  frameRate(30);

  oscP5 = new OscP5(this, 8338);

  canvas = createGraphics(640, 480, P2D);

  // Create syhpon server to send frames out.
  server = new SyphonServer(this, "FaceOSC Processing Syphon");
}

void draw() {  
  canvas.beginDraw();
  canvas.background(255);
  canvas.stroke(0);

  if(face.found > 0) {
    canvas.translate(face.posePosition.x, face.posePosition.y);
    canvas.scale(face.poseScale);
    canvas.noFill();
    canvas.ellipse(-20, face.eyeLeft * -9, 20, 7);
    canvas.ellipse(20, face.eyeRight * -9, 20, 7);
    canvas.ellipse(0, 20, face.mouthWidth* 3, face.mouthHeight * 3);
    canvas.ellipse(-5, face.nostrils * -1, 7, 3);
    canvas.ellipse(5, face.nostrils * -1, 7, 3);
    canvas.rectMode(CENTER);
    canvas.fill(0);
    canvas.rect(-20, face.eyebrowLeft * -5, 25, 5);
    canvas.rect(20, face.eyebrowRight * -5, 25, 5);

    print(face.toString());
  }
  canvas.endDraw();
  image(canvas,0,0);
  server.sendImage(canvas);
}

// OSC CALLBACK FUNCTIONS

void oscEvent(OscMessage m) {
  face.parseOSC(m);
}

// a single tracked face from FaceOSC
class Face {

  // num faces found
  int found;

  // pose
  float poseScale;
  PVector posePosition = new PVector();
  PVector poseOrientation = new PVector();

  // gesture
  float mouthHeight, mouthWidth;
  float eyeLeft, eyeRight;
  float eyebrowLeft, eyebrowRight;
  float jaw;
  float nostrils;

  Face() {}

  // parse an OSC message from FaceOSC
  // returns true if a message was handled
  boolean parseOSC(OscMessage m) {

    if(m.checkAddrPattern("/found")) {
        found = m.get(0).intValue();
        return true;
    }      

    // pose
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/pose/scale")) {
        poseScale = m.get(0).floatValue();
        return true;
    }
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/pose/position")) {
        posePosition.x = m.get(0).floatValue();
        posePosition.y = m.get(1).floatValue();
        return true;
    }
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/pose/orientation")) {
        poseOrientation.x = m.get(0).floatValue();
        poseOrientation.y = m.get(1).floatValue();
        poseOrientation.z = m.get(2).floatValue();
        return true;
    }

    // gesture
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/gesture/mouth/width")) {
        mouthWidth = m.get(0).floatValue();
        return true;
    }
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/gesture/mouth/height")) {
        mouthHeight = m.get(0).floatValue();
        return true;
    }
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/gesture/eye/left")) {
        eyeLeft = m.get(0).floatValue();
        return true;
    }
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/gesture/eye/right")) {
        eyeRight = m.get(0).floatValue();
        return true;
    }
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/gesture/eyebrow/left")) {
        eyebrowLeft = m.get(0).floatValue();
        return true;
    }
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/gesture/eyebrow/right")) {
        eyebrowRight = m.get(0).floatValue();
        return true;
    }
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/gesture/jaw")) {
        jaw = m.get(0).floatValue();
        return true;
    }
    else if(m.checkAddrPattern("/gesture/nostrils")) {
        nostrils = m.get(0).floatValue();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  // get the current face values as a string (includes end lines)
  String toString() {
    return "found: " + found + "\n"
           + "pose" + "\n"
           + " scale: " + poseScale + "\n"
           + " position: " + posePosition.toString() + "\n"
           + " orientation: " + poseOrientation.toString() + "\n"
           + "gesture" + "\n"
           + " mouth: " + mouthWidth + " " + mouthHeight + "\n"
           + " eye: " + eyeLeft + " " + eyeRight + "\n"
           + " eyebrow: " + eyebrowLeft + " " + eyebrowRight + "\n"
           + " jaw: " + jaw + "\n"
           + " nostrils: " + nostrils + "\n";
  }

};
```

Note, this is merged code that isn't tested. 
It should get the point across, but I can't test right now.

Make sure the sketch is running before you launch VPT (otherwise, restart VPT)

[image: FaceOSC to Processing to Syphon to VPT]